# Error when trying to connect to sentinel with password using ioredis nodejs module

Tags: node.js, docker, redis, redis-sentinel, ioredis

I am trying to use ioredis to connect to my sentinel service under docker which require a password in my config.
Here is my code :

```
sentinels: [
{ host: "192.168.0.35", port: 26379 }
],
name: "redismaster",
sentinelPassword: "sentinelPassword",
sentinelRetryStrategy: function(times) {
// reconnect after
return Math.max(times * 100, 3000);
}
});
```

But it doesn't succeed. Here is the log when activate DEBUG=ioredis :

```
2020-02-07T18:06:10.091Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.0.35:26379]: [empty] -> connecting
2020-02-07T18:06:10.093Z ioredis:redis queue command[192.168.0.35:26379]: 0 -> sentinel([ 'get-master-addr-by-name', 'redismaster' ])
2020-02-07T18:06:10.096Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.0.35:26379]: connecting -> connect
2020-02-07T18:06:10.097Z ioredis:redis write command[192.168.0.35:26379]: 0 -> auth([ 'thisis1SentinElP@sSwOrd' ])
2020-02-07T18:06:10.097Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.0.35:26379]: connect -> ready
2020-02-07T18:06:10.097Z ioredis:connection send 1 commands in offline queue
2020-02-07T18:06:10.098Z ioredis:redis write command[192.168.0.35:26379]: 0 -> sentinel([ 'get-master-addr-by-name', 'redismaster' ])
2020-02-07T18:06:10.100Z ioredis:redis write command[192.168.0.35:26379]: 0 -> sentinel([ 'sentinels', 'redismaster' ])
2020-02-07T18:06:10.101Z ioredis:SentinelConnector Updated internal sentinels: [{"host":"192.168.0.35","port":26379}] @1
2020-02-07T18:06:10.102Z ioredis:SentinelConnector resolved: 192.168.0.23:6379
2020-02-07T18:06:10.105Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.0.23:6379]: connecting -> connect
2020-02-07T18:06:10.106Z ioredis:redis write command[192.168.0.23:6379]: 0 -> info([])
Redis connected
2020-02-07T18:06:10.106Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.0.35:26379]: ready -> close
2020-02-07T18:06:10.106Z ioredis:connection skip reconnecting since the connection is manually closed.
2020-02-07T18:06:10.106Z ioredis:redis status[192.168.0.35:26379]: close -> end
Redis error in (/config/redis.js) ReplyError: NOAUTH Authentication required.
```

According to the logs, i see that my redis client can connect to sentinel, it also find the real redis server under sentinel mode and select the database. I get the log that redis is connected, but after that, the connection is closed.
Where am i missing ?

PS: i did add also the config snetinel-annouce-ip in case my redis client doesn't recognize the ip of sentinel, but in the logs, it got the good private ip : 192.168.0.35.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to set password to both `password` and `sentinelPassword`

```
{ 
  sentinels: [
    { host: "192.168.0.35", port: 26379 }
  ],
  name: "redismaster",
  password: "yourpassword",
  sentinelPassword: "yourpassword"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It works for me now. Because i also put an authentication to redis, we must put the password of redis instance also in the password attribute. I thought that when connecting to sentinel, the rest will be done automaticly because sentinel has the redis password. But we must put it also in ioredis.

Comment: yeah, your case is same as mine.

Comment: Thank you. I have also another issue, when the failover is done, the slave become a master and the master become the slave. After, ioredis will switch automoticly.  but the problem that i face is when i execute the command `DEBUG sleep 60` to stop the master and cause the failover, ioredis will not accept requests ( get and write ) even if we had a new master. it still not work until the new slave is UP after 60 seconds. Can we change this behaviour ?

Comment: I have get error when try add `password` to connection options `[ioredis] Unhandled error event: Error: All sentinels are unreachable. Retrying from scratch after 10ms`. Can you help?